# Trying to resample data and the columns are off by 1

Tags: resampling, maxent

I am trying to run a MaxEnt model with layers from ArcGIS.

I am new to MaxEnt modeling but from what I have learned everything must be exactly the same in all layers. Columns, rows, cell size, projection, etc.

I have run a resampling tool and set the extent to a default raster, and have run a raster snap to the same layer. The main issue is the columns are slightly off and I have not been able to figure out how to set them to the exact same.